# How to copy list of folders keeping the partial folder structure that of parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I want to copy some folders from `find /40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD -name "plink_data*"` which has these folders:

```
/40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD/ADGC_NHW/ADNI/TOPMEDr2/vcffile/plink_data
/40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD/ADGC_ASIAN/BIOCARD/TOPMEDr2/vcffile/plink_data
```

into `/40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD/NEW_DIR/`, but I want the new directory to have :

```
/40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD/NEW_DIR/ADGC_NHW/ADNI/TOPMEDr2/vcffile/plink_data
/40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD/NEW_DIR/ADGC_ASIAN/BIOCARD/TOPMEDr2/vcffile/plink_data
```

I tried this but it copies the whole path: `find /40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD -name "plink_data*" -exec cp --parents {} /target \;`

How do I go about doing it? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I was able to perform my task with `cp` using answer from @Cyrus, but not with `mv`. I thought applying `cp` and `mv` in this command would not be any different, but I was wrong. In fact, I needed to use both `mv` and `cp` for different tasks, so I resorted to using a loop

```
for line in $(find . -name "*plink_data*"); do
    new_FOLD="$(echo  $line| cut -d"." -f2-)"
    mkdir -p "NEW_DIR/${new_FOLD}"
    cp/mv $line "NEW_DIR/${new_FOLD}"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
cd /40/AD/GWAS_data/Source_Plink/2021_ADGC_EOAD
mkdir -p NEW_DIR
find . -name "plink_data" -not -path "./NEW_DIR/*" -exec cp --parent {} NEW_DIR \;
```